PJSIP: TX packet loss
What are reason for packet loss on TX in PJSIP:
TX pt=96, ptime=60, last update:00h:00m:00.030s ago
total 2.4Kpkt 556.3KB (656.0KB +IP hdr) @avg=29.2Kbps/34.5Kbps
pkt loss=621 (24.9%), dup=0 (0.0%), reorder=0 (0.0%)

and how to find the root cause for such a packet loss?
